# Microsoft LifeCam-VX700 v2.0 Audio is just static

Tags: skype

Running Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS 32-bit on a computer with an Intel core i5 processor, 4GB RAM and a NVIDIA 450GTS Graphics card.

I am trying to set up Skype with my webcam. So far everything works almost perfectly, however my Microsoft LifeCam-VX700 v2.0 audio does not work correctly. The audio feed is just static/white noise.

I have checked the hardware using windows and it worked perfectly there. The video works great in Ubuntu. It is just the audio that is the problem.

What can I do to rectify this problem?

Comment: I think you should probably be running a 64 bit Ubuntu with that spec. Why did you go for 32?

Comment: It's still reproducible the problem?